# Failed to compile: 'props' is not defined no-undef in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to pass a function to a a React Router but it gives me an error despite several adjustments. I tried putting the function in the render(), added *this* before params props, but nothing seems to be working. How do you you pass a function to selective return between a Route and a Redirect tag?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import DogList from './DogList';
import DogDetails from './DogDetails';

class Routes extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getDog = this.getDog.bind(this);
  }

  getDog() {
      let name = props.match.params.name;
      let currDog = this.props.dogs.find(
          dog => dog.name.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase()
      );
      if(currDog != undefined) {
        return <DogDetails {...props} dog={currDog} /> ;
      } else {
        return <Redirect to="/dogs" />
      }
    }

  render() {
    
    return(
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/dogs' render= {() => <DogList dogs={this.props.dogs} />} />
        <Route exact path='/dogs/:name' render={(props) => {this.getDog()}} />
        <Redirect to='/dogs' />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}

export default Routes;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to seperate your components because there might be so many routes, so, you might not be able to manage them in one component.

Anyway, in your case please try sending props as a parameter to your function.

You should wrap your switches with BrowserRouter.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import DogList from './DogList';
import DogDetails from './DogDetails';

class Routes extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getDog = this.getDog.bind(this);
  }

  getDog(props) {
      const { dogs } = this.props;

      let name = props.match.params.name;
      let currDog = dogs.find(
          dog => dog.name.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase()
      );
      if(currDog != undefined) {
        return <DogDetails {...props} dog={currDog} /> ;
      } else {
        return <Redirect to="/dogs" />
      }
    }

  render() {
    const { dogs } = this.props;
    
    return(
      <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/dogs' render= {() => <DogList dogs={dogs} />} />
        <Route exact path='/dogs/:name' render={(props) => this.getDog(props)} />
        <Redirect to='/dogs' />
      </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Keep in mind this react router documentation. It is a good guide to your example; https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

A complete example is here; https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-ishizaka-n0433?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. when I try this, it basically just shows a blank page when you go to '/dogs/something'. Probably not able to access that element in the dogs array, which I passed as prop to Routes from the App component. And it gives TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined when I used this.props.param

Comment: @Samarth Actually the problem here is different. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.props` not only `props`

```
let name = this.props.match.params.name;
```